# where is the class HttpClientExtensions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, client

I was looking into this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client). I tried the git mentioned in the link. The extension functions `PostAsJsonAsync`, `ReadAsAsync`and `PutAsJsonAsync` were not found. When I looked them up, they all belonged to the `HttpClientExtensions` class. However I am unable to find this class anywhere. I did find [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions(v=vs.118).aspx), but I do not find this class inside the `System.Net.Http` namespace. The project from git simply shows errors on these extension functions. 
 I have tried looking for this class in the latest versions of .net standard and .net framework. I have looked into nugets and add reference > assemblies.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? The System.Net.Http was added in .NET 4.5

Comment: when i cloned the git it was on 4.5.1. I updated it to 4.7. Both didn't work

Comment: I got the same problem a few weeks ago. Try to install this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost/5.2.2

Comment: I tried installing it, but what is it for? it seems to be setting up web api 2. My api is set up in .net core

Comment: Well. If that's not the right for you you can install the System.Net.Http per hand. https://i.imgur.com/E7ghIMm.png

Comment: well.. that's already imported